# Build a Google Suggest box and respond to keyboard events without jQuery

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

I need to build a Google Suggest style drop-down box, but unfortunately am unable to use jQuery or Prototype due to various licensing restrictions. Pretty much the only thing I can use is public-domain stuff that I can modify and am not required to attribute ownership of someone else to.

In any case, I can handle the AJAX stuff fine, and the server-side scripting. Where I'm stuck is how to make Javascript respond to keyboard events:

- Select the next item in the list when the user hits the down arrow key
- Select and fill the text box with the selected item when they hit [Enter]
- Close the suggest box when they hit [Esc]
- etc. etc. etc.

Thoughts? Examples?

Comment: Why is it you can't use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but might be of interest. [A fancy Apple.com-style search suggestion using jQuery](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/a_fancy_apple.com-style_search_suggestion.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to attach/detach events (compatible with both IE and W3C event models, so should work in all browsers):

```
events = {

    addEvent: function(obj, e, handler) {
        if (!obj._attachedEvents)
            obj._attachedEvents = new Array();
        if (obj._attachedEvents[e])
            this.removeEvent(obj, e);
        obj._attachedEvents[e] = handler;

        if (obj.addEventListener) 
            obj.addEventListener(e, handler, false);
        else if (obj.attachEvent) 
            obj.attachEvent('on' + e, handler);
    },

    removeEvent: function(obj, e) {
        if (!obj._attachedEvents || !obj._attachedEvents[e])
            return;

        if (obj.removeEventListener) 
            obj.removeEventListener(e, obj._attachedEvents[e], false);
        else if (obj.detachEvent) 
            obj.detachEvent('on' + e, obj._attachedEvents[e]);
        obj._attachedEvents[e] = null;
    },

    cancelEvent: function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;

        if(e.preventDefault)
            e.preventDefault();
        if(e.stopPropagation) 
            e.stopPropagation(); 
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    },

    getTarget: function(e) {
        return e.srcElement || e.target;
    }
};
```

and then in the handler you can see what key was pressed and do whatever action you want in response to that.

Hope it helped,
Andrey

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [js-hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/). I've used this library in many projects. It works in all A-grade browsers which allows you to catch key-events, and the license is pretty liberal.